# Trying to create default parameters for the child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, default-value

I want to create a class that will be a able to create a subclass. Here is an example of code:

```
class System:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0, c=0):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c
        self.sub_systems = []

    def create_sub_sys(self, a=None, b=None, c=None):
        if a is None: a = self.a
        if b is None: b = self.b
        if c is None: c = self.c
        ss = System(a, b, c)
        self.sub_systems += [ss]
        return ss

s = System(a=10, b=100, c=-19)
s1 = s.create_sub_sys()  # want it to be exact same system, so a, b, c = 10, 100, -19
s2 = s.create_sub_sys(b=3)  # create system with a, b, c = 10, 3, -19
s21 = s2.create_sub_sys(a=3, c=3)  # so a, b, c all are 3. 'b' parameter inherits from a 's2' class
print(s1.a, s1.b, s1.c)
print(s2.a, s2.b, s2.c)
print(s21.a, s21.b, s21.c)
```

So child classes should take parameters, as parent have, if there are no parameters given by a user to that subclass. The code above is working, but it seems to be quite poor made. If i will have lots of parameters, there will be lots of lines of code. And also, this program that i posted is checking, if parameters are None. But I am making a program, where 'None' will actually means something (program should not assign parents parameter), so code will not working.

It is actually very hard to formulate a question, but I hope you can understand the code. So the system I want should check if the user have used some parameters of the class. If so, it will override parent's that are given by default. If not, it will leave parent's. Maybe you can give me advice how to improve it, make it more general (None in the code states, that I can't make some parameters of the child to be None type even if I want)

Comment: You could write `def __init__(self, **kwargs)` (same for `create_sub_sys`) and work with the `kwargs` dictionaries (and their methods) which is much easier.

Comment: Terminology note: you keep using terms like subclass, and parent/child class. That implies *inheritance*. There is no inheritance here. This is composition.

Comment: " If i will have lots of parameters, there will be lots of lines of code. " That isn't the bad part, lots of lines of code isn't a problem.  The bad part is that if you change the signature of the constructor, it requires changing this code, but that is always the case when you refactor an API. This is much less of a problem if you use static analysis tools, most IDEs/text-editors will have linters that will catch this. You can also just use `mypy`/`pyright` static type checkers, although, that may be more than what you want

Comment: @MichaelButscher it is true that it makes it easier, however, it makes the constructor accept *any* arguments, which is a significant negative IMO. Of course, you can manually check that the  `**kwargs` passed are ones you want, but then it seems like that takes away from the aforementioned simplification of the implementation! Personally, I prefer just writing this out as it is above and I use static analysis tools like mypy so if I refactor the constructor I find all the places I have to refactor calling the constructor.

Comment: Note, you should follow PEP 8 style conventions, and `self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c` should be spread out into seperate lines, and conditional statements shouldn't be on a single line, e.g. `if a is None: a = self.a` should be two seperate lines, indented

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the information. _Note, you should follow PEP 8 style_ - yea, I know that, I just did that to make less lines of code, Pycharm is pointing that that is not completly good.  _it makes the constructor accept any arguments…_ absolutely agree. That were my thoughts on the first comment there. But I can use kwargs in sub_sys function acually. I will post my idea.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The manual check of `kwargs` is easy and, in its own method, could be used for constructor and `create_sub_sys` (and maybe further methods). But I understand that this is less useful in combination with a linter or static type checking.

Comment: @DanyaK I know you can, my point is, you *shouldn't*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you look at my solution I have posted below? The way I did will not makes the constuctor to accept ant arguments. But I will have a look at _static analysis tools_, maybe that will be indeed better to use

Answer (score 2):

My solution using kwargs:

```
class System:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0, c=0):
        self.kw = locals().copy()
        self.kw.pop('self')  # no need to have self as a parameter
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c
        self.sub_systems = []

    def create_sub_sys(self, **kwargs):
        ss = System(**self.kw | kwargs)
        self.sub_systems += [ss]
        return ss

s = System(a=10, b=100, c=-19)
s1 = s.create_sub_sys()  # want it to be exact same system, so a, b, c = 10, 100, -19
s2 = s.create_sub_sys(b=3)  # create system with a, b, c = 10, 3, -19
s21 = s2.create_sub_sys(a=3, c=3)  # so a, b, c all are 3
print(s1.a, s1.b, s1.c)
print(s2.a, s2.b, s2.c)
print(s21.a, s21.b, s21.c)
```

The only problem I can see there is that create_sub_sys parameter kw, makes code writing harder, as you will not know, which parameters could be there.

Any thoughts about this code?

Comment: i'm not a fan of `self.kw = locals()` in `__init__`, but you could use `ns = vars(self); del ns['sub_systems']; ss = System(**(ns | kwargs))` or in older versions of python, `ss = System(**dict(**ns, **kwargs))`. then you don't have to keep `self.kw` around

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I like, how you are combining dictionaries. But that code leads to an error. Probably because `del ns['sub_systems']` for some reasons is actually equivalent to `del self.sub_systems`. Using `ns = vars(self).copy()` seems to reduce this problem. Also, in a case if i will have lots of instances of the class, I will have to delete all of them that are not parameters, which is not convenient. But thank you for your help anyway

Comment: This is buggy. Values passed to `create_sub_sys` are [incorrectly retained across calls](https://ideone.com/5tMG7w).

Comment: @user2357112 I know. That is an not updated answer. I can update it to remove this bug. In a new version I've deleted line `self.kw.update(kwargs)` and replace `ss = System(**self.kw)` to `ss = System(** self.kw | kwargs)`.

Comment: @user2357112 now it should work correctly

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts about this code?

In this case, using the variable names directly is more clear. Clarity and simplicity will help you maintain and read your code. Not to mention mitigate bugs. Try to avoid unnecessary fanciness. Creating a copy of an instance of something with three variables should remain visually simple, it can then convey that nothing fancy is going on. The reader can then focus their attention elsewhere.

For that reason, it's a good idea not to mutate the super-system when making a subsystem. That adds complexity and violates the boundaries between the objects. It also deceives the user when they read the method name. `create_sub_sys` doesn't give the impression that the current instance will be changing in any way. If the super-system has to change, give it a new method that only handles that change of internal state.

Additionally, avoid abbreviations: it's preferred to use whole words. So, `subsystem` instead of `sub_sys` or `ss`.

> Maybe you can give me advice how to improve it, make it more general

The only difference between `system.create_subsystem()` and `subsystem = System(subsystem_config)` is that you're appending to the list of subsystems. But, that's really not enough to justify a whole method, particularly when lists already have a method to do that. You could consider a `register_subsystem` method, that could customize how subsystems are kept track of.

I've modified the example for simplicity and clarity, with more generality and commentary.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass()
class SystemConfig:
    a: int = 0
    b: int = 0
    c: int = 0

    def conditional_copy(self, a=None, b=None, c=None):
        """makes a copy with parent attributes if None provided."""
        return self.__class__(
            a=self.a if a == None else a,
            b=self.b if b == None else b,
            c=self.c if c == None else c,
        )

class System:
    """docstring describing the class with a usage example."""

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.subsystems = []  # do the subsystems know about the super-system?

system_config = SystemConfig(a=10, b=100, c=-19)
system = System(system_config)

# The creation of subsystems might be better extracted to where
# they are created. It's a bit of a code smell for the `System`
# class to have a method which takes arguments that a component
# needs, like the indirection of passing in a, b and c.
subsystem_config = system.config.conditional_copy(b=3)
subsystem = System(subsystem_config)
system.subsystems.append(subsystem)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advices. In the example I indeed using 3 parameters, in my real code there will be at least 10, some of which can take a value of 'None', so code will significantly become more complex. _create_sub_sys doesn't give the impression that the current instance will be changing in any way_ my function doesn't change anything (except the sub_systems list). Probably you wrote that paragraph before I've updated the code or I don't understand something.

Comment: Yes, 10 parameters is likely going to be an issue. I'd suggest breaking them up along conceptual lines. For instance, one class could be `SystemConfig`, if they are values specific to the `System` which determine how it will operate. Another example class could be like `SpeakerSystem` or `ProjectorSystem`. And all of those things come together to make the `System`, whose `__init__` takes instances of those classes. It will then have fewer parameters, and they'll be better organized.

Comment: Maybe it works. But doesn't this code already look quite complicated? The code should only take parents parameters by default. But using such things code will already be getting all attention from a user. In my example (using kwargs) It just take few lines, and so easier to explain purpose, less modification and thinking needed for the program, general working without specifying special case for 'None'. Also adding new parameter will need to do lots of modifications to this code. But I will think about what you've suggested, maybe that is indeed better.

Comment: Chew on it for a while. These are only suggestions. Systems have a tendency to grow. 10 parameters will have a tendency to slide to 15, or 25, in the future. Creating abstractions is done to tame the complexity of living systems, with declarative and precise organization. Code which has no need to be changed or maintained, because it works, may have no need to be organized with care. I'm sure the solution you decide on will be best for your use-case. Here's a great talk which lead me down my path of learning: https://youtu.be/n0Ak6xtVXno?t=60